Definizione lessicale di "qualunquista"
Il termine qualunquista è piuttosto usato nel gergo politico italiano, con lontana origine nell'indicare i simpatizzanti del movimento politico italiano dell'«Uomo Qualunque».
Mi sono reso conto che non saprei descrivere compiutamente il senso/significato usualmente associato a qualunquista.
Nel Gabrielli (on line) leggo

Chi professa o manifesta indifferenza e sprezzante distacco nei confronti di ogni forma di impegno politico e sociale

che non mi sembra colga le principali sfumature.
La Treccani (on line), per l'avverbio  qualunquisticaménte, ha

con atteggiamento di indifferenza e scetticismo o di generica protesta verso le istituzioni e le questioni politiche

che pure non mi convince.
La domanda è quindi: quale definizione lessicale è appropriata per qualunquista?

Condivido: pochi anglofoni conoscono la parola “qualunquismo”, ma basta porre su English.SE una domanda in cui descrivi il concetto per il quale ti serve una parola inglese. È una cosa che si fa sia qui sia lì: qual è una parola per esprimere la tal e tal idea?

Non saprei descrivere il significato di qualunquista, forse neppure in italiano, sicuramente non in inglese :-( > Vedi Edit

Ho modificato il tuo post in modo da eliminare le parti off-topic. Ho riformulato anche leggermente il titolo perché nel modo in cui era sembrava qualcosa di opinion-based.

Concordo che in questo modo la domanda è interessante e in tema.

Dovresti specificare perché le definizioni date da due fonti autorevoli non ti convincono.

@Mr Black. la prima suggerisce un atteggiamento aristrocratico, manca completamente il riferimento alla presunta condizione dell'uomo comune. La seconda è meglio, ma eviterei di usare 'scetticismo'.
